# Put mbox on the right even if a newline is just before it

Tags: horizontal-alignment, line-breaking

I want to write two words on the right of the page. `sometext TWO WORDS` so I put a `\hfill` just before and because I don't want any break in the two words, I use `\mbox`:

```
sometext \hfill \mbox{TWO WORDS}
```

But sometimes I have a really long text before `\hfill` and so a line break is put but always after the `\hfill`. So `TWO WORDS` stay on the left.

I've tried using `ragged` possibility without any success.

So how can I break before the `\hfill` or justify part of the sentence to the right?

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16330/hfill-after-linebreak

Comment: @UlrikeFischer oops. I've made some research before asking the question but don't see this one. Thank you

Comment: One can't always find relevant answers. I had the advantage to know that it is there.

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/91548/bump-right-aligned-text-to-next-line-iff-no-room

Comment: I'd advise you to use @WillRobertson's solution, as that is way more stable than my "works-sometimes-but-not-always" solution.  At least then you won't get any nasty surprises.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's important to remember that `\hspace` and `\hfill` "collapse to zero" at the beginning of a line. `\hspace*`, on the other hand, does not. Others have already mentioned this, but there are few more subtleties to take into account.

```
\newcommand\OnRight[1]{%
  \unskip           % (1)
  \hfill            % (2)
  \penalty100\relax % (3)
  \hspace*{0.5em}%    (4)
  \hspace*{\fill}%    (5)
  \mbox{#1}%          (6)
}
```

1. prevent leading spaces from affecting output
2. don't set the current line with justification
3. prefer line-breaks to overfull lines
4. a default "hard space" that needs to be included
5. the pushing-right flexible space
6. the unbreakable content itself

Minimal example below that demonstrates some (not all) of these features.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\OnRight[1]{%
  \unskip\hfill\penalty100\relax\hspace*{0.5em}\hspace*{\fill}\mbox{#1}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item a short line \OnRight{\fbox{abc xyz}}
  \item a single line that is longer but edging towards two but not quite \OnRight{\fbox{abc mno xyz}}
  \item a single line that is xx longer but edging towards two but not quite \OnRight{\fbox{abc mno xyz}}
  \item a single line that is extra longer but edging towards two but not quite \OnRight{\fbox{abc mno xyz}}
  \item a single line that is extra longer but edging towards two but not quite quite \OnRight{\fbox{abc mno xyz}}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

**Update:** Ulrike suggests (I think) the following improvement:

```
\newcommand\OnRight[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \parfillskip=0pt\relax
    \unskip\hfil\penalty100\relax\hspace*{0.5em}\hfil\mbox{#1}%
    \par
  \endgroup
}
```

I am not entirely sure that you always want to insert `\par` in there, so I'll leave both solutions for now `:)`

Comment: You should also set (locally) \parfillskip to 0pt.