# Keep text as a block and horizontal fill

Tags: macros

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{libertine}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\customquote}[2]{%
{\textit{#1}}\hfill\mbox{#2}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\customquote{We had this charming girl at the university. Her name was Virginia. 
We called her Virgin for short---but not for long.}{Keith McNeil}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{document}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

I would like to be able to push the `source` to far right. (1) If there is enough space to contain it, without breaking, with the first text, then it should not be on a new line, (2) else, it shall be on a new line and flushed right. The above code manages to achieve (1) but not (2). How can I achieve both?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16333/2388

Comment: @Ulrike Thanks. Shall I delete the question?

Comment: That or you could answer your own question, so that in the future people can get the answer faster …